# html2canvas override css (font)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas javascript library to take a screenshot of my app for feedback functionality purpouses. However my app contains sensitive presonal data that i don't want to be readable on the screenshot. So i've created a font that every glyph looks like a circle (similar to password inputs in IE). My question is:

Is that possible to somehow tell html2canvas to render everything with this font? I have a css rule that applies this to every element on the page. Now i'm adding a css class to `body` element, then i run html2canvas, and then i remove the class to get original fonts. But for the time of rendering canvas the user can see these strange glyphs and i don't want them to see that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to add `data-html2canvas-ignore` attribute to the elements that contains sensitive information, before rendering..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the html2canvas library is pretty simple in its implementation.  I tried a few different ideas, and what you CAN do is hide the ugly text rendering with an overlay, as long as the overlay sits outside of the element you call html2canvas on.

```
// Hide your content with an overlay
$( '.snapshotoverlay' ).css( 'display', 'block' );

// .. then do your ugly modifications
$( '.previewWrap' ).css( 'background', 'red' );

// make sure your overlay div isn't contained in the div you're screenshotting.
html2canvas($('.content'), {  

    onrendered: function (canvas) {

        // do whatever you need to with the resulting canvas object
        var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        $('#canvasImg').html('<img src="'+canvasImg+'" alt="">');

        // undo your ugly changes
        $( '.previewWrap' ).css( 'background', 'black' );

        // hide your overlay
        $( '.snapshotoverlay' ).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle where the box is coloured red during screenshotting, but you never see the red because of the overlay:

http://jsfiddle.net/tommcquarrie/tJmQ7/

I think it actually adds something to the screenshot experience.  Add a camera click sound and you'd emulate iOS 7 :)

Comment: I need to render a vast amout of HTML (approx. 3000 elements) and the rendering takes about a second. So hiding everything for a second with an overlay doesn't look good.

Comment: Is the user clicking a button to take the screenshot, or are you taking it without their knowledge? If it's the latter, there's no way of doing it.  If it's the former, then showing an overlay with a nicely designed graphic saying "Taking screenshot..." is perfectly acceptable.